# How can i change music led controller color with SP107E / Flutter

Tags: flutter, bluetooth, controller, connection, led

I want to change my **music led color** **(SP107E)** , is that possible with flutter ? What is the correct way for this ? I find some libraries but i couldnt use it.

I am already connected to device but i cant write values.

In this example which i am using this for now.

https://github.com/alvarowolfx/ble-rgb-light-flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vU0Q.png)

I just want to change led colors.

UPDATE:

Im getting this error when i try to pick a color.

```
Tried calling: write(Uint8Array, withoutResponse: true)
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:63:5)
#1      _DeviceScreenState.writeData
package:ble_rgb_lamp/main.dart:305
#2      _DeviceScreenState.onColorChange.<anonymous closure>
package:ble_rgb_lamp/main.dart:320



void writeData(Color color) async {
    try {
      var colorStr =
          color.value.toRadixString(16).padLeft(8, '0').substring(2, 8);
      var obj = {'color': colorStr};
      var cmd = jsonEncode(obj);
      List<int> bytes = utf8.encode(cmd);
      print(cmd);
      await rxChar.write(bytes, withoutResponse: true);
      timer = null;
    } on Exception catch (err) {
      print(err);
    }
  }

void onColorChange(BuildContext context, Color color) async {
    setState(() => pickerColor = color);

    if (rxChar == null) {
      await fetchServices(context);
    }

    if (timer == null) {
      timer = Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 100), () => writeData(color));
    }
  }
```

**I found documentation SP107E**

https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/91v2W3TbWeL.pdf

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the libraries you tried and why they did not work for you. Connecting to a BLE device using flutter is definitely possible. Writing the correct values to an unknown device might be tricky. Do you have any documentation for the SP107E?

Comment: Hi Michael , actually i dont have any documentation about SP107E. I can connect with bluetooth to device. But i cant do anything about led color.